# Oddity with multiple inheritance from two template parameters?

Tags: c++, templates, multiple-inheritance

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename E1, typename E2>
class Mix : public E1, public E2
{
public:
    Mix() : E1(1), E2(2)
    {  
        // Set nothing here
        cerr << "This is " << this << " in Mix" << endl;
        print(cerr);
    }

    void print(ostream& os)
    {
        os << "E1: " << E1::e1 << ", E2: " << E2::e2 << endl;
        // os << "E1: " << e1 << ", E2: " << e2 << endl; won't compile
    }
};

class Element1
{
public:
    Element1(unsigned int e) : e1(e)
    {
        cerr << "This is " << this << " in Element1" << endl;
    }

    unsigned int e1;
};

class Element2
{
public:
    Element2(unsigned int e) : e2(e)
    {
        cerr << "This is " << this << " in Element2" << endl;
    }

    unsigned int e2;
};


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   Mix<Element1, Element2> m; 
}
```

Now, since we're equally inheriting from the two template parameter classes, I would expect `this` to be the same in the two constructors, but this is not the case. Here is the run log:

```
This is 0x7fff6c04aa70 in Element1
This is 0x7fff6c04aa74 in Element2
This is 0x7fff6c04aa70 in Mix
E1: 1, E2: 2
```

As you can see, while `this` is the same in Element1 and Mix, this is not true for Element2. Why is that? Also, I would expect to have access to e1 and e2 from the base classes. Can you explain this behavior?

Comment: Why should Element1 and Element2 have the same adrress? they are not the same object.

Comment: Also, you can get access to `e1` and `e2` from base class, just add `this->` before them. Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3799495/template-inheritance-c).

Comment: @soon thanks, I used to know about that, but temporarily forgot. :)

Comment: "_Also, I would expect to have access to e1 and e2 from the base classes._" Hug? What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Element `Mix` contains an `Element1` and an `Element2`. These are - perhaps implementation specifically aligned - written after one another in memory. If you use `Mix` as `Element1`, this will point to the first of the two (with size of `Element1`), if you use it as `Element2` it will point to the second (with size of `Element2`) and if you use it as `Mix` it will point to the base address, which is the same as `Element1`s base address, but has a differenz size (at least size of `Element1` + size of `Element2`).

Edit: You can verify this by outputting the size too:

#include

```
using namespace std;

template <typename E1, typename E2>
class Mix : public E1, public E2
{
public:
    Mix() : E1(1), E2(2)
    {  
        // Set nothing here
        cerr << "This is " << this << " + " << sizeof(*this) << " in Mix" << endl;
        print(cerr);
    }

    void print(ostream& os)
    {
        os << "E1: " << E1::e1 << ", E2: " << E2::e2 << endl;
        // os << "E1: " << e1 << ", E2: " << e2 << endl; won't compile
    }
};

class Element1
{
public:
    Element1(unsigned int e) : e1(e)
    {
        cerr << "This is " << this << " + " << sizeof(*this) << " in Element1" << endl;
    }

    unsigned int e1;
};

class Element2
{
public:
    Element2(unsigned int e) : e2(e)
    {
        cerr << "This is " << this << " + " << sizeof(*this) << " in Element2" << endl;
    }

    unsigned int e2;
};


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   Mix<Element1, Element2> m; 
}
```

Output:

```
This is 0x7fffc9cad310 + 4 in Element1
This is 0x7fffc9cad314 + 4 in Element2
This is 0x7fffc9cad310 + 8 in Mix
E1: 1, E2: 2
```